# ESP32 FreeRTOS (ESP-IDF) Передача в задачу несколько параметров

Tags: esp32, freertos

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.
Начал изучать ESP32. Работаю с ESP-IDF. Проблема возникла буквально сразу. Решил для тренировки создать такс (задачу) для мигания светодиода. Подключил к модулю два светодиода. Захотел помигать светодиодами с разной частотой. Для этого надо создать два экземпляра задачи с разными параметрами (номер пина и чатоста мигания). Код использую следующий:

```
    /*
Программа мигающая двумя светодиодами. Демонтстрирует FreeRTOS.
Есть одна задача, которая принимает в себя параметры pinName - номер пина, где висит светодиод и timeDelay - время задержки между переключением уровней
Создаем две задачи и передаем в них номер пина и время задержки
*/
#include <stdio.h>

#include "driver/gpio.h"

#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"


#define LED1    GPIO_NUM_23
#define LED2    GPIO_NUM_22



// задача переключающая состояние порта куда подключен светодиод
void blinkLED(void *pvParameters)
{
    printf("The task blinkLED has started!\n");
    /* Объявляется структура для приема параметров */
    struct param_t {            // структура с типом param_t
        int numLED;         // номер пина где светодиод
        int durationLED;       // длительность включения/выключения светодиода
    };
    /* принятые параметры приводятся к типу созданной структуры */
    struct param_t *ReceiveParam;                   // объявляется указатель на структуру
    ReceiveParam = (struct param_t*)pvParameters;   // приводится к типу созданной структуры

    while (1)
    {
        printf("tick 1\n");
        gpio_set_level(23, 1);
        printf("tick 2\n");
        vTaskDelay(ReceiveParam->durationLED);
        printf("tick 3\n");
        gpio_set_level(23, 0);
        printf("tick 4\n");
        vTaskDelay(ReceiveParam->durationLED);    
    }
    
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}


void app_main(void)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(LED1);
    gpio_set_direction(LED1, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(LED2);
    gpio_set_direction(LED2, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    /* Объявляется структура передаваемых параметров */
    struct param_t {            // структура с типом param_t
        int numLED;         // номер пина где светодиод
        int durationLED;       // длительность включения/выключения светодиода
    };

    // заполняем передаваемые параметры для каждого экземпляра задачи.
    const struct param_t SendParam1 = {LED1, 100};
    // const struct param_t SendParam2 = {LED2, 100};

    // создаем задачу для первого светодиода и передаем туда параметры из структуры выше.
    printf("try to create task1 for blink\n");
    xTaskCreate(blinkLED, "blinkLED1", 1024*2, (void*)&SendParam1, 3, NULL);
    // xTaskCreate(blinkLED, "blinkLED2", 1024*2, (void*)&SendParam2, 3, NULL);
    // xTaskCreate(blinkLED, "blinkLED2", 1024, ( void* ) LED2, 3, NULL);
    
}
```

Светодиод не мигает. просто зажигается и все. В код уже добавил сообщения, которые выводятся в COM порт.
Выводятся сообщения:

try to create task1 for blink
The task blinkLED has started!
tick 1
tick 2
Т.е. походу параметры я передаю не так. Подскажите - в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что Freertos обнуляет стек функции main при запуске планировщика, руководствуясь логикой, что программа не вернется в эту функцию. А у вас структуры создаются внутри main. Что бы ваш код заработал необходимо сделать структуры глобальными.

Answer (score 0):

Другой вариант, передавайте структуру в задачу через очередь. Например:

```
void blinkLED(void *pvParameters)
{
    printf("The task blinkLED has started!\n");
    /* Объявляется структура для приема параметров */
    struct param_t {            // структура с типом param_t
        int numLED;         // номер пина где светодиод
        int durationLED;       // длительность включения/выключения светодиода
    };
    /* принятые параметры приводятся к типу созданной структуры */
    struct param_t ReceiveParam;                 
    xQueueReceive(qHost,&ReceiveParam,portMAX_DELAY); //задача ждёт пока не заберёт свою структуру из очереди

    while (1)
    {
        printf("tick 1\n");
        gpio_set_level(23, 1);
        printf("tick 2\n");
        vTaskDelay(ReceiveParam->durationLED);
        printf("tick 3\n");
        gpio_set_level(23, 0);
        printf("tick 4\n");
        vTaskDelay(ReceiveParam->durationLED);    
    }
    
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void app_main(void)
{
   struct param_t {           
        int numLED;         
        int durationLED;       
    };
   const struct param_t SendParam1 = {LED1, 100};
   QueueHandle_t qHost;
   qHost = xQueueCreate (1, sizeof(SendParam1));
   xQueueSend(qHost,&host,1);
   xTaskCreate(blinkLED, "blinkLED1", 1024*2, NULL, 3, NULL);
}
```